# Handling multiple key-press event on C#  windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

Is there a way to handle the multiple key-press event on a C# windows form, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> ?

Here's my code:

```
private void frmDataEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
{  
   if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
   {  
          //Code  
   }              
}
```

This condition is always false .. why? I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and e.KeyCode is false and  Control.ModifierKeys is true? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

It should be:

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.E) {
    //Code
}
```

Control.ModifierKeys is for `onClick` events and the like.

Answer (score 3):

I think the condition you're looking for is

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: this yields a slightly different behaviour than my answer. my condition is only true for Ctrl+E while this is also true for Ctrl+Shift+E, Ctrl+Alt+E, etc.